# How to mock a CrudRepository call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mocking, mockito

I am trying to make a simple controller test on a Spring MVC application

I have this test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class, WebAppConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class NotificacaoControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private NotificacaoRepository notificacaoRepositoryMock;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        //We have to reset our mock between tests because the mock objects
        //are managed by the Spring container. If we would not reset them,
        //stubbing and verified behavior would "leak" from one test to another.
        Mockito.reset(notificacaoRepositoryMock);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void add_NewTodoEntry_ShouldAddTodoEntryAndRenderViewTodoEntryView() throws Exception {
        Notificacao added = new Notificacao(123,"resource","topic", "received", "sent");

        when(NotificacaoRepository.save( added )).thenReturn(added);
```

my TestContext class has this bean

```
@Bean
public NotificacaoRepository todoService() {
    return Mockito.mock(NotificacaoRepository.class);
}
```

and my repository is just that

```
public interface NotificacaoRepository extends CrudRepository<Notificacao, Long> {
}
```

but it didn't even compile, I keep getting "***Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method save(Notificacao) from the type CrudRepository***" on the last line "**when(NotificacaoRepository.save( added ))**"

I saw this kind of use on an example in this link http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-normal-controllers/ but there he uses a service class and it is not exactly like the use of CrudRepository.

I tried to find an example of how to test a CrudRepository implementation but didn't find one, so I am thinking this should be simple like others mocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the save method is not static, you will have to change

```
  when(NotificacaoRepository.save( added )).thenReturn(added);
```

To use an object as:

```
when(notificacaoRepositoryMock.save( added )).thenReturn(added);
```